# how to fetch not empty only columns in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to show some info in my php page . for example :

```
<p>Name of Item : <?php echo $name; ?></p>
<p>Price : <?php echo $price; ?>
```

I want labels (name of item, price ) should be shown in my page only when the product info is not empty in database .

Comment: Neat. Show us the code you tried and we can help you figure out what's wrong with it.

Comment: nothing wrong there, i just want to add an extra feature, labels will only be visible when the columns are not empty :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `empty`:

```
<?php if (!empty($variablenotempty)){ ?>
<p>Name of Item : <?php echo $name; ?></p>
<p>Price : <?php echo $price; ?></p>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: thank you for relevant answer , I have tried !empty , but still it's showing labels for non empty columns

Comment: _should be shown in my page only when the product info is not empty_  , So if is empty don't show no?

Comment: yes you got it right, your code is ok too , but somehow it's not working for me . Is there any alternative code ?

Comment: Have you close `</p>` ? i didn't see.